# Custom UserStore not loading Roles even with Include

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm working with Identity 2.2 and I'm having problems getting a User from the UserManager with the Roles property loaded.  I've overridden the UserStore with a custom FindByIdAsync. The method gets called, but the roles still aren't loaded.

```
public class AppUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public AppUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public override async Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        var result = await _context.ApplicationUsers.Include(x => x.Roles).FirstOrDefaultAsync(n => n.Id == userId);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I also have the following relevant code in the context.

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
            .HasKey(r => new { r.Id })
            .ToTable("AspNetRoles");

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>()
            .HasKey(r => new { r.Id })
            .ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany<IdentityUserRole>((ApplicationUser u) => u.Roles);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>()
            .HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId })
            .ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany<IdentityUserRole>((ApplicationUser u) => u.Roles);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
            .HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId })
            .ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");
    }
```

Comment: if you inspect the "result" variable inside FindByIdAsync method Roles are null?

Comment: Yes, they are.  But there is definitely data for that user in the AspNetUserRoles table

Comment: What is purpose of overriding `OnModelCreating` and writing mappings manually ?

Comment: @SteveWash, If all else fails then forego the include and do another search for roles where the user's id exists and add them to the outgoing result.

Comment: Thanks, NKosi. There SHOULD be a better way, but that would work I believe.